# Fortran program cannot compile

Tags: linux, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I get this error when I try to make my fortran program, how can I solve this?

```
mpifort verison: GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5
gfortran version: GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.2.0
mpirun version :  3.2.1


 gfortran -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/external -I/usr/local/include    -I/usr/local/include  -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/Share -D'SVN_REV="tag-   4.6.1"' -O3 -fconvert=big-endian -fno-range-check -fPIC -c mod_mpmessage.F90
 gfortran -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/external -I/usr/local/include   -I/usr/local/include  -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/Share -D'SVN_REV="tag-  4.6.1"' -O3 -fconvert=big-endian -fno-range-check -fPIC -c mod_regcm_types.F90
 gfortran -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/external -I/usr/local/include -  I/usr/local/include  -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/Share -D'SVN_REV="tag-  4.6.1"' -O3 -fconvert=big-endian -fno-range-check -fPIC -c mod_runparams.F90
 mpifort -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/external -I/usr/local/include   -I/usr/local/include  -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/Share -O3 -fconvert=big-  endian -fno-range-check -fPIC -c mod_mppparam.F90
 mod_mppparam.F90:22.6:

 use mod_intkinds
  1
 Fatal Error: File 'mod_intkinds.mod' opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file
 make[3]: *** [mod_mppparam.o] Error 1
 make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: No I used these commands 1. ./confiigure CC= gcc FC=gfortran 2. make which then fails. Any suggestions about how to rectify this?

Comment: I use this to delete it ::  find . -type f -name "*tkinds.mod" -delete but when I use make clean and then make it comes back and I get the same error.....

Comment: Can you show us the output of mpifort --version and gfortran --version , please?

Comment: Sure @ Ian mpifort version GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 and gfortran is GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.2.0 thanks

Comment: OK, that's probably it - module files for the reasonably modern 8.2 are not compatible with the ancient 4.8.5. What version of mpi are you using? (and please edit the question to include the information you have just given us)

Comment: Hi @ Ian I have updated the question accordingly. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The simplest way might just be to use mpifort to compile everything. But it would be best to avoid such an old version. What version of mpi are you using? OpenMPI? If you tell us we might be able to tell you how to persuade mpifort to use the newer compiler. Also in the code do you include 'mpif.h' or use mpi?

Comment: Hi Ian this is the version of mpirun that I am using at the moment. mpirun (Open MPI) 1.6.3. Also this is a climate model written by someone that I am trying to use from this website (https://gforge.ictp.it/gf/project/regcm/frs/). instructions to install include down file unzip and cd into the folder. Then you cofigure with ./configure after which you make and finally make install. I am completely new to fortran as I am using python. How can I use mpifort to compile? Thanks

Comment: OK - last I'll say as stackoverflow is nagging me due to its belief that every question has a simple answer. The best way to solve this is to install a new version of OpenMPI which uses gfortran 8.2, or at least have a consistent compiler used by gfortran and mpifort. However you might first try make clean and the export OMPI_FC="path to gfortran 8.2" making the obvious change and remaking (see https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/ question 5). This may or may not work, depends on the program. As I say the real problem is your version of OpenMPI is out of date.

Comment: Thanks Ian for the help appreciated.